# Charge distribution on a line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, conductors

Given a conducting line segment from -a to a, with a total charge Q distributed by the continuous charge density $\lambda(x)$. I can write this system of integrals.

Since the charge must total Q:
$\int_{-a}^a \lambda(x)dx=Q$

Since at any point along the line, the E-field strength from both sides must be equal to be in equilibrium: 
$\int_{-a}^X \frac{\lambda(x)}{(X-x)^2}dx = \int_{X}^a \frac{\lambda(x)}{(X-x)^2}dx$

This must be true for all values $-a \lt X \lt a$.

I'm interested in finding a $\lambda(x)$ function that will satisfy this. How can I approach this?

Comment: Sounds like you understand all the concepts. What's your question?

Comment: I have no idea how to approach finding a function that will work with the integral. I imagine there is someway to make it into a differential equation but the math is beyond me.

Comment: Hm, intuitively I'd start with your equality, bring the righthandside over and demand that this should be 0 exactly. Then interpret this as a function of X and compute the derivative. That will be a bit tricky because both the integral limits and the function inside the integral depend on $X$, so maybe you have to do it "by hand", by explicitly substituting $X + dX$ for $X$, expanding to first order in $dx$, then subtracting the $X$-only part. This should hopefully give a useful equation for $\lambda$.

Comment: So, instead of working on my thesis I looked more into this and can't find a simple way to solve this, so I did some googling and found this paper by EM god David J. Griffiths: http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys3320/phys3320_sp12/AJPPapers/AJP_E&MPapers_030612/Griffiths_ConductingNeedle.pdf

Turns out there is no simple answer...

Comment: You are WAY overthinking this problem.  Like charges repel.  Due to this, ALL charges MUST reside on the surface of a conductor, and for a line segment that has a constant "diameter" (assuming that it is round), the charges MUST become evenly distributed over the line segment because of their mutual repulsion.

Comment: I don't think that is a valid conclusion. If we imagine positive charges constricted to a line (even the surface of a cylinder is just a lot of parallel lines) then we know they cannot be evenly distributed. If they were, any off-center charge would feel a greater repulsion from the center than from the edge.

Comment: That would work for the single case where the net charge is 0, and having a constant 0 charge density does satisfy the equations I wrote if Q=0.